# MongoSync has problem to connect with docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-kafka-connect

Good night .

I am tryng to connect with the following connector: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector a sync with topic on kafka to update MongoDB

I can connect to my docker container image with MongoCompass but when I try to configure a connector always receive an error.

This is my connector.

And my curl petition

curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @register-mongobd.json

```
{
"name": "mongo-sinkV2",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:64000",
    "database": "MUR",
    "collection": "collecitonTest2",
    "topics": "dbserver1.inventory.addresses",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": true,
    "mongo.errors.tolerance": "all",
    "mongo.errors.log.enable": true,
    "change.data.capture.handler": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.ChangeStreamHandler"
}}
```

I always receive the same error.

{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nUnable to connect to the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}

This is how I deploy my mongo database with docker,

docker run --name mongodb -d -p 64000:27017 mongo

Could anyone helps to me ? I think I had my connector not installed correctly.

I need to replicate data between kafka topic and MongoDB . For this I need to configure the sync connector.

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka connect container is not running Mongo; localhost is not correct, and needs to be the address of the Mongo container

If you started Kafka Connect with Docker Compose, you should add the Mongo container to that, not use a separate docker run command. Similarly, you need to use port 27017 between the containers; the connection doesn't go over your forwarded host ports, therefore your Compass connection string is meaningless.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/